# Calendar.before(Object when), why Object?

Tags: java, calendar

From the javadoc of `Calendar.before(Object when)`:

Returns whether this Calendar represents a time before the time represented by the specified Object. This method is equivalent to:

```
compareTo(when) < 0
```

if and only if when is a Calendar instance. Otherwise, the method returns false.

Why does it accepts an Object if when someone passes something that's not a Calendar instance it returns false? Why not just accepting a Calendar instance? This kept me watching for uncorrect results in a functionality for quite some time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is no particular reason for that. `java.util.Calendar` has some design issues we have have to live with, unfortunately.

Comment: +1. Note that the Date object (whose design issues Calendar was supposed to address) has a before method that does not take an Object (but another Date). Not a particularly consistent API.

Comment: By "live with" do you mean dump in favor of Joda Time?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the method is not `final` (and the class itself abstract). Feel free to subclass it and provide a version which will take Java’s `Date` or JodaTime’s `LocalDate`. If you see it that way, it turns out that it was very far-sighted of the JDK’s authors to provide such a general solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think this may be to provide encapsulation by using polymorphic behaviour in the before() method.