# Why Calendar.before() and Calendar.after() accept object value?

Tags: java, date, datetime

I was having a problem because I was trying to pass a Date to Calendar.before() and Calendar.after() instead of passing a Calendar.

If a date is passed these methods always return false.

Comment: The method first checks if `when instanceof Calendar`. The javadoc says so `if and only if when is a Calendar instance`. As to why, I have no idea.

Comment: I believe there isn't a good reason. The Calendar API is universally agreed to be poorly designed. JDK 8 really fixes everything, but many can't upgrade. Joda time is a third party substitute for people who can't use JDK 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be because someone could write a subclasses of `Calendar` that work with various data types, like Date, without breaking the `Calendar.before(Object)` or `Calendar.after(Object)` method signature. **There is no other good reason which you can think of**. So possibly you have to live with it.

You may also check out [Calendar.before(Object when), why Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758982/calendar-beforeobject-when-why-object)

Comment: A subclass of Calendar still safely and automatically casts to Calendar, so that's not a valid justification.

Comment: @user2684301:- Yes I agree that it is not a valid justification but I thought of it. I think there is possibly no good justification for this!

Answer (score 0):

calender before and after receive an object not a date formated as string
to make it work try to send:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
cal.setTime(sdf.parse("Mon Mar 14 16:02:37 GMT 2011"));

Calendar.before(cal);
```

that should do it.

as to why - dont think there is really a good reason for that the whole class is complicated beyond reason.

Comment: The OP was asking *why*, not *how*.